# How should I remove sample data populated via self.up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should I remove sample data in the self.down method(s) for both the migrations listed below

```
class FooSampleData < ActiveRecord:Migration

  def self.up
     Foo.create(:bar => 1)
     Foo.create(:bar => 2)
     Foo.create(:bar => 3)
  end

  def self.down
  end
end

class FooSampleDataV2 < ActiveRecord:Migration

  def self.up
     Foo.create(:bar => 4)
     Foo.create(:bar => 5)
     Foo.create(:bar => 6)
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Comment: Is :bar unique? You just want to delete that 3 records? You are using a migration version only for adding sample data? Why don't you use seed?

Comment: bar is supposed to be unique. Yes, I am using the migration utility to add data to a table which will not contain user specified data just whatever is specified by the system. How do I populate seed data, kindly clarify

Comment: check http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating your database table at the same time, then destroying table will destroy data.

If :bar is unique, you may find by bar and destroy the object.

> ```
> # up
> Foo.create([{:bar => 1},{:bar => 2},{:bar => 3})
>
> # down
> Foo.where(:bar => [1,2,3]).each { |foo| foo.destroy }
> ```

**Edited**

I don't know your scenario. Seed usually is used for starting up an application. If you are in an incremental development (with deploys) usually initial data is included when we create our model, and not in a exclusive migration as you show in your example.

If you really need to do it in a exclusive migration, your drop work will be proportional do your create work.

In my projects I avoid adding data in migrations.

Some useful links:

- [Rails Guides: migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)
- [Rails Casts: seed data](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)

Comment: The ids which I provided above are quite simple in nature and in our environment we have a large number of barIds which are not sequential necessarily. Also, how would you delete the entire table of data, if you want to

Comment: You should do your homework. There are plenty of information about migrations. I updated my answer. You gave me a simple scenario and I gave you a simple answer to :D.

Comment: Thanks for your answer(s). I am just asking from the forum, since I wasn't able to solve it by myself. Wish I had the clarity to solve these issues. I still feel my underlying issue is not yet resolved